# imported Python module not initializing internal imports

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have a Python / Pygame module which has the structure as given below. This is saved as a python file named text_factory.py.

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import KEYDOWN, K_ESCAPE, RLEACCEL

class Text_Factory(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, posx = None, posy = None, font = None, fontsize = 100, colour = (255, 50, 64), text1 = "Level ", text2 = " Complete!",  level = 1, frames = 30, pause = 1500, slowdown = 30, fade = False, rotate = None):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()

        if self.screen == None:

            if sys.platform == 'win32' or sys.platform == 'win64':
                #os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '0'# center of screen
                os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (10, 30)#top left corner

            self.screen =pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), 1, 32)  # demo screen size

            back = pygame.image.load("D:\\IMAGES\\space_11.jpg").convert()
            self.screen.blit(back, (0, 0))

        # the subsurface is a rect
        self.subsurface = None  #self.screen.subsurface(0, 0, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height()).convert_alpha()
        self.background = (0, 0, 0)
        self.alpha = 255
        if posx == None:
            self.posx = self.screen.get_width() / 2
        else:
            self.posx = posx
        if posy == None:
            self.posy = self.screen.get_height() / 2
        else:
            self.posy = posy
        self.center = (self.posx, self.posy)
```

etc. etc.

When I import it from another python file like below

```
from text_factory import *

tf = Text_Factory()
tf.default() # this is a function in the class to demnstrate the code
```

> the program stops running with the pygame.error: font not initialized message.

Apparently the pygame module is not loaded and initialized. Aren't the pygame, sys, os and other imports supposed to run when the code is called and run the way shown above? When I import text_factory which is a python module, shouldn't it run the internal imports? If not how is that done?

Answer (score 0):

MY BAD!
I had simply not done `pygame.init()` inside the class. Once I inserted that everything worked fine.